# "Is there any way to see actual source code of React widget & make add things in it?

Tags: reactjs

I need to understand how React Widgets are created and accordingly, I need add functionality on it. For example, I have used below widget

npm install --save @opuscapita/react-dates

I want add some functionality on it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source code on their GitHub repository. You can then clone it, make changes and issue a pull request to their repo, or fork it and maintain your own version. Check the license.

[repo](https://github.com/OpusCapita/react-dates/issues)